# Querying SVNKit for log information about a specific file

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I want to query our SVN server to return log entries about a **specific** file.
What I've tried to do :

```
SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup();
SVNURL svnURL = SVNURL.parseURIDecoded("svn://our-server:3692/branches/hotfixes/3.5.12345/");
SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(svnURL);
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager("anonymous", "anonymous");
repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);   
Collection logEntries = repository.log(new String[] { "/src/java/testsProject/depends.list" }, null, 0, -1, true, false);
```

I get this exception:

> org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: File not found: revision 126600, path '/src' at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64‌​) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51‌​)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What is going wrong at present?

Comment: I get the following exception

org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: File not found: revision 126600, path '/src'
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
...

Comment: This means that path '/src' doesn't exist at HEAD revision, you should specify revision at which the path existed